# Symfony2 - Sonata datagrid without entity

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-sonata

Is there a way to take advantage of the Sonata's Datagrid functionnality to display a resultset ?

```
class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    public function nl_listAction()
    {
        $obj = array();
        $cnx = $this->get('doctrine.dbal.a_connection');
        $cnx->query('CALL(a_procedure)');
        $obj['cnx'] = $cnx;
        return $this->render('GlideConfigBundle:Default:nl_list.html.twig', $obj);
    }
}
```

Here from a controller I'm calling a procedure and I'd like to display the resulting data using Datagrid.
Is it a good idea ?
How can I do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ended up by using only the [bootstrap table styles](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables) with my own templates/macros.
Also I had to kind of reinvent the wheel by doing filter widgets, list widgets, and pager :( ...